# Efficient full-text search on a filesystem

Tags: bash

What is the most efficient way to perform full-text searches on files in a filesystem?

Comment: ... "Binarise"?

Comment: "Compile" may be a better word

Comment: Not really. Index might be. Brute-force search, use your OS's find, grep, etc. If it's a structured file, consider loading it into a database engine like SQLite and then working on it.

Comment: This sounds more like a question for [Super User](http://superuser.com) of [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: This question is overly broad. You should narrow its scope and be more specific. Otherwise `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 grep ...` or `find ... -exec grep ... +` are the most general-purpose answers that are efficient enough. Specifying the starting directory and the proper options will do a lot for efficiency. Indexed searches are very fast, but the index has to exist first. It all depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: In what context do you need this?  Are you looking for a desktop search engine for you personal system or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If the number of queries greatly exceeds the number of changes to the files then the most efficient way to perform full-text search is to use a pre-built index that gets updated when files are added, changed or removed.

The type of index needed depends on the type of searches. For example, do you search on words or phrases? Do you want to take into account synonyms? Do you search on word-fragments?

What kinds of efficiencies are you looking for? Development time efficiency? Efficiencies in software licencing costs? CPU time efficiency? Disk IO efficiency? The way  you weight these will have a large effect on which solution is optimal for you.

See also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search)